# IE11 on Win7, console seems broken

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I upgraded my Win7 test box to use IE11, the released version.

When using the developer tools (F12), I switch to the console.

At the bottom is the text box where you can enter commands and have the console execute the javascript command....

Except it doesn't.  All that happens is the console window prints the command, as if it was a piece of text.

Did I switch to a different console mode on accident?

Comment: Could you share a screencap of the console after you entered your commend(s)?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen if you are debugging. I was able to execute commands in the console when not debugging. However, when I was stepping through the script console didn't evaluate anything. That makes it absolutely useless. It worked fine in IE10.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem also, and found that updating IE fixed it as this post describes:
[Debugger not working in IE 11 F12 developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573817/debugger-not-working-in-ie-11-f12-developer-tools)