# Script pane missing from IE Debugger after upgrade Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Upgraded to Windows 10 about a month ago,

Noticed that in Internet Explorer 11 that the scripts pane in the debugger isn't visible.  Running Edge which seems to have an identical look & feel to the Developer Tools the pane is present.

Unclicked the default settings in IE 11 that disable JavaScript debugging but that has no effect.  Wondering if IE 11 is using parts of Edge and that is causing the debugger issue?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've been struggling with the same problem for a while, just after updating to windows 10, and even if it's a bit late, might help others. In my case, it turned out to be the most stupid thing ever: the script pane was there, but hidden behind the Wacthes and CallStack panes. You just need to go to the left and shrink to the right a bit those panes. See pics:

No script pane:
[image: No script pane]

Script pane was hidden!:
[image: Script pane was hidden!]

Also, other steps I did just before noticing:

- I enabled script debugging (Internet options > Advanced > Under Browsing uncheck the "Disable script debugging"). <= This is actually needed for actually debugging once you get your scripting pane back.
- Disabled IE11 and enabled it again.
- Reset defaults, etc.

But nothing made the pane appear, it was just this silly thing so easy to "fix". I hope is the same for you!

Comment: Forgot about this post and solved the same way. ;-) Thanks for answering! Likely save somebody a headache

Comment: couldn't imagine it could be this silly thing. you are life saver today.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but can't find anything to grab to resize :-/

Comment: For future people with this issue: eventually by docking it again and a lot of continued effort I did manage to grab and resize it and now it's working.

Comment: oh thank christ i found this.  What a stupid feckin' design that allowed that.  I thought i was going nuts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You made my day after spending for few hours to fix this stupid stuff!

Comment: Resetting Defaults and docking the F12 window helped see the handle to grab on the left edge to expand and expose the soiurce window. be sure all instances of IEXPLORE.exe are dead after resetting.

Comment: I think at least 3 times a day that microsoft developers are made up of some malicious techies finding fun aggravating their users.  I couldn't believe they overlap those 2 lines so perfectly that nobody can find the script window until somebody accidentally mouse-dragging on those 2 lines.  Another aggravating thing is their evil balloons pop up anywhere they want so you cannot see your code even I didn't ask for those hints.