# Not able to identified the element from <iframe>

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Our webpage is designed with a lot of iframes and it supports only IE browser.

I am trying to get the *MF:txtProgramId* element from  the iframe, so  I can switch over to specific iframe successfully. But the selenium Webdriver is not picking the id=*MF:txtProgramId* from the iframe. Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Details:
Source file:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vpccvAgL9XXvAAne36bWNqG0FkZbbnCm/view?usp=sharing
Browser: IE only.

Comment: Please share the HTML

Comment: Source file attached in below link:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vpccvAgL9XXvAAne36bWNqG0FkZbbnCm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Kindly help me to resolve

Answer (score 0):

The element is not inside iframe. You can directly access it without switch to any frame.

```
WebElement inputbox = driver.findElement(By.id("MF:txtProgramId");
```

Comment: Could please share your entire selenium code?? So that i can check it in my application.

Comment: I have tried with watir ruby. the code is, browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'file:///C:/Users/trainee/Downloads/pgmid.html'
browser.text_field(id: 'MF:txtProgramId').set "value"

Comment: Actually, The thing is we can access the id=MF:txtProgramId element by parsing the DOM like your above method. But we cannot access this element in our web application and its throwing an error such as No such element found.

Comment: but, the element is not inside the frame as per the html source.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support. our element are presented inside the iframe only. but while try with IE-11 it is showing empty. thats reason element are not find by driver.it is brower issue (Ref: [Debugger not working in IE 11 F12 developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573817/debugger-not-working-in-ie-11-f12-developer-tools) )