# F12 debugger tool not finding running add-ins

Tags: debugging, office365, office-addins, cpu-word

Having an issue with debugging an Office Word add-in using F12. Up until lately, it was working fine, but then my company enforced a Windows update and I started having problems. F12 does not appear to find any programs running. I'm using Windows 10 (64bit), Adding an image for reference.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please check the below link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016654/14520925

Comment: it's not really clear, F12 debugging? Typically we talk about F10,F11 when we're talking about stepping through code. Are you talking about the Edge Developer Tools? And what's the F12 shortcut? What are the repro steps?

Comment: @J.FelixBosco Tried that one. didn't work. Thanks.